# How do I prevent user from entering specific characters in a textbox using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have a regular expression that will be matched against the keypress of the user. I'm quite stuck with it.

Here is my current code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('input.alpha[$id=tb1]').keydown(function (e) {
        //var k = e.which;
        //var g = e.KeyCode;
        var k = $(this).val();
        //var c = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
        if (k.value.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
</script>
```

The goal here is to prevent the user from typing characters that are inside the regex.

Comment: "Here is the error message on IE9.": where ?

Comment: Also why `k.value`, when `k = $(this).val()`? Have you checked for duplicates? I am sure there are many similar questions on SO. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2919898/944681), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7543059/944681), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2500620/944681) and many more..

Comment: I've been tweaking the codes that's why it's bit messy. What I'm trying to do is if the user pressed a character in the keyboard and it matches the regex it will prevent default.

Comment: @randelramirez1: Is there something unclear about my answer that I can clarify for you?

Comment: @randelramirez1 main problem of your script is, that `$(this).val()` is input's value **before** key was pressed, that means you don't check last key pressed..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the [fromCharCode](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_fromcharcode.asp) method:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#tb1').keydown(function (e) {

    var k = String.fromCharCode(e.which);

    if (k.match(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g))
      e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: There is just one problem with this. It blocks the backspace key as well.

Comment: @MichaelS.Miller If you want to keep backspaces as well, just add `\x08` to the regex: `/[^a-zA-Z0-9\x08]/g`.

Answer (score 4):

You use `keypress` rather than `keydown` and prevent the default action.

For example, this prevents typing a `w` into the text input:

```
$("#target").keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which === 119) { // 'w'
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

[Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/ohaxud/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ohaxud/1/edit)

**Update**: If it's applying the regex that's giving you trouble:

```
$("#target").keypress(function(e) {
  if (String.fromCharCode(e.which).match(/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/)) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

[Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/ufukaj/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ufukaj/1/edit)